# Assinatura de Email buga no Gmail

Tags: css, html5, gmail

Eu criei uma assinatura de email em HTML, no Thunderbird ela funciona, mas no Gmail ela buga, parece não interpretar o css.

```
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Assinatura Sitear</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        @font-face{font-family: "tw-cent"; src:url("http://www.sitear.com.br/img/ass/font.ttf");}
        hr{margin-bottom: -3px;}
        small{ font-size: 10pt; color: #BBB; margin-left: 5px;}
        body { font-size: 12pt; font-family: "tw-cent"; }
        a { color: #5D5D5D; text-decoration: none;}
        a:hover{ text-decoration: underline;font-weight: bold; color: #148f07;}
        body ul { list-style: none; }
        body li { display: inline-block; line-height: 2px;}
        #logo img {padding: 10px 30px 10px 0; margin: 10px 30px 10px 0; border-right: 3px solid #CCC; }
        #info img{ margin: -3px 5px -3px 0px; position: relative; top: 2px;}
        #info { position: relative; top: -17px;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="ass">
        <li id="logo">
            <img src="http://sitear.com.br/img/ass/miniatura.png" height="100" width="100">
        </li>

        <li id="info">
            <h3>Clara Battesini<small> Webdesigner</small></h3>
            <hr>
            <h4><a target="_blank" href="http://www.sitear.com.br">www.sitear.com.br</a></h4>
            <h5><img src="http://sitear.com.br/img/ass/email.png"><a href="mailto:suporte@sitear.com.br">suporte@sitear.com.br</a></h5>
            <h5><img src="http://sitear.com.br/img/ass/tel.png"><a>(71)9926-0999</a> / <a>(71)9655-7318</a></h5>
        </li>
    </ul>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Será que o GMail aceita o HTML completo, digo com esta declaração <HTML>, <BODY>? Pensei que deveria utilizar um fragmento, o que estiver dentro do BODY, e o CSS, você utiliza Inline, ao invés do <HEAD>

Comment: Obrigada, estou colocando todo o css inline aqui.

Comment: O ideal é se ater ao HTML 4, e evitar CSS em email.

Comment: @ClaraBatt se a sua resposta já está satisfatória para você, pode aceitá-la como a correta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bom pelo que pude ver, o gmail simplesmente ignora a tag `<style></style>`. Logo aplicando o css todo "inline" ele funcionou. Tive que trocar a lista por uma tabela.

Comment: Pra uma tecnologia geriátrica como o Email nada como a boa e velha `<table>` :)

Comment: @brasofilo panela velha é que faz comida boa :)